How can I send and receive from Gmail account in Outlook.com?
In Yahoo Mail, I can add my Gmail account using Settings -> Manage Accounts, so that I can send and receive Gmail  messages from within Yahoo Mail.
How can I configure Outlook.com with my Gmail account to do the same thing?

You Can't Add External Accounts
You used to be able to, however Microsoft removed the ability to add them from Outlook.com in 2021. Any external accounts added before that date still worked until Microsoft completely disabled the feature in 2024.
Included w/ Paid MS-365 Subscriptions
If you pay for a subscription to Microsoft 365 Basic, Personal or Family, you can add external accounts.
Options for Outlook.com Users
Microsoft now suggests that Outlook.com users either:

Forward external account messages to Outlook.com

Forward Gmail messages to another account
Yahoo Mail Free removed automatic forwarding from their web app in 2021. Apparently it can be done with a paid account, Yahoo Mail Plus or Access+Forwarding (USA)


Access external accounts using one of Microsoft's standalone apps:

Outlook for iOS or Android
Outlook for Windows or Mac
Windows 10 Mail



